# How to pause timer till procedure within finish in Flutter

Tags: mysql, flutter, timer

I'm using timer for refreshing data from

```
timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 60), (Timer t) async {
      await getList();
})
```

Its working fine.
I want to pause timer until getList proc completed. The proc itself take 30 to 120 second.

So is their any option to pause timer?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What do you want to do with this timer? Because you start it 60 seconds after the first initialization. What do you really want to do?

Comment: I retrieve data from Server. Some times its 1 record sometime 1000. Don't know how much time it will be consuming.

Comment: Do you want to refresh your data every 60 seconds or every 60 seconds AFTER you have received all your data. That's two different ways of doing it

Comment: after receiving data.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open [issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/43329) for your problem. Dart sdk doesn't provide pause or restart feature for Timer. You can use [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/pausable_timer) which does the job for you. Or use `Stream.periodic()` which was mentioned in the [comment](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/43329#issuecomment-687696954). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will prefer this kind of solution.

```
  late Timer timer;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    callDataWithPause60Seconde();
  }
```

```
callDataWithPause60Seconde() {
    Future.doWhile(() async {
      print("Call getList()");
      // await getList();
      timer = await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 60));
      return true;
    });
  }
```

don't forget to cancel timer

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    timer.cancel();
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
  }
```